# Why can't I Monkey-patch __setitem__ on a subclass of collections.MutableMapping

Tags: python

Usually, I can willy-nilly monkey-patch and mock methods:

```
from UserDict import DictMixin
class py2fake_dict(DictMixin):
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        raise AssertionError("Don't talk to me!")
    def __delitem__(self, name):
        pass
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        yield None
    def __len__(self):
        return 0

c = py2fake_dict()
c.__setitem__ = lambda name, value: 'All clear.'
# This is OK:
c[1] = 2
```

However, if the method in question is on a MutableMapping subclass, I cannot:

```
from collections import MutableMapping
class py3fake_dict(MutableMapping):
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        raise AssertionError("Don't talk to me!")
    def __delitem__(self, name):
        pass
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        yield None
    def __len__(self):
        return 0

c = py3fake_dict()
c.__setitem__ = lambda name, value: 'All clear.'
# This hits the assertion!!!
c[1] = 2
```

I found this in working code when upgrading from `UserDict.DictMixin` to `collections.MutableMapping` as part of our Python3 upgrade. I'll remove the code, or use subclass in the future, but **I just want to understand what is happening.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can monkey-patch methods on the class just fine, but monkey-patching magic methods on *instances* of a [new-style class](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) hasn't worked since new-style classes were introduced back in Python 2.2. New-style classes are `object` and its descendants, and for many reasons (better performance, less weird edge cases, support for new features like `super` and `property` setters, Python 3 compatibility), you should prefer new-style classes over old-style whenever possible.

`UserDict.DictMixin` is an old-style class. Setting magic methods on instances only works on instances of old-style classes. `collections.MutableMapping` is a new-style class.

In Python 3, there are no old-style classes, so you're going to have to get used to magic methods only working if set on a type.